# Geo: Need to convert a "place name" into an "canonical place name"

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

Our users can enter their location into a free-form text field, like "Austin TX", or even "The Motor City". How can I take this information and turn it into a canonical name? For example, "The Motor City" would be Detroit, MI. They might even enter a zipcode or an address.

I'm planning on storing the place name, or the lat/long, or the unique id code for their location in the database. Then I can determine proximity. Is there a geo lookup api I can use for this?

Comment: That's funny.  Translate The Collar City.  The Electric City.  Quite funny.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo has a nice open API for dealing with this kind of thing, WOEID's (Where on earth); query the WOE DB for your freeform string, it'll give you back a WOEID, then Query the WOEID for whatever actual data you want to store.
http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html

Comment: In particular, it's their Placemaker API that handles conversions of free-form text into standard geographic concepts. (I think I've heard "The Motor City" used as an example, but I can't verify that offhand.)  http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placemaker/

Comment: You're correct, and the motor city commect is from the Open Hack NYC conference http://developer.yahoo.net/blogs/theater/archives/2010/03/think_place_not_space.html